# ssh agent forwarding troubleshooting

Tags: ssh

I am struggling to diagnose why one particular server does not honour the agent forwarding I have setup.

From client (macOS) I can `ssh -A` to any number of servers and on them can see that `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set, and `ssh-add -L` shows my key.

On one particular host this does not work. When I login `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set, but `ssh-add -L` says "`this agent has no identities.`"

Firstly my sense is that if `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set then the agent forwarding has worked in the sense that `AllowAgentForwarding` is enabled on client and server (which I've checked to be true).

For example:

On the problematic host:

```
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-ZpxzssfdPuZq/agent.14304

$ ssh-add -l
This agent has no identities.
```

And for the ssh server on that host I find these mentions of 'agent' in the sshd logs when `DEBUG3` is set:

```
Jul  4 xxxxxxx hostname sshd[14924]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request auth-agent-req@openssh.com reply 0
Jul  4 xxxxxxx hostname sshd[14924]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
Jul  4 xxxxxxx hostname sshd[14924]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req auth-agent-req@openssh.com
```

Correspondingly on the client (macOS), I see this with `ssh -vvv hostname`:

```
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug2: channel 0: request auth-agent-req@openssh.com confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
```

So that covers all the options and scenarios my knowledge of ssh and its config comprise.  So I am asking what further steps I might do to source the problem, or what I'm missing more obviously.

Thanks

r.

Comment: On the problematic machine, are you logging into an existing `screen` or `tmux` session, or is the variable set by the user's shell's startup files?

Comment: I am not using screen or tmux sessions.  From the client terminal I am simply issuing ssh -A <hostname>.  I am not explicitly setting any variable.  SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set by ssh by dint of using -A (agent forwarding).

Answer (score 2):

The comment from Kusalananda was useful - pointed me toward checking things. Contrary to my thoughts, I did have 'eval $(ssh-agent)' in $HOME/.bash_profile of the problematic server.  I just didn't think to check that. That obviously overwrote the socket.  Reason was that server was historically used as a source for connections to other servers and at that time I used an agent on it.